# One JSP getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Attribute "var" was already specified for element "c:set"

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am new to Java server development, I am converting a web app written in ColdFusion into a Java EE web app on Glassfish 4. This app is JSP heavy (where servlets would be best used). That is by design and not my decision.

The error is:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>
> #### PWC6170: Validation error messages from >TagLibraryValidator for sql
>
> null: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; >lineNumber: 1726; columnNumber: 3; Attribute "var" was already specified for >element "c:set".

It appears that these very few JSPs do not accept the taglib reference. Here is an example (identical in all files):
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

I've found that if I remove the "jsp/" section of the URI attribute, the error goes away (but then I can't use EL expressions in `<c:set>` tag). So I'm wondering if I somehow have two different versions of JSTL in my web container?

Here is my web.xml (removed the bottom part with all the servlets):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Many (hundreds) of JSPs work fine with this taglib, and they are in mixed directoried/locations so I don't really know why this is happening. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I found the issue. There was a c:set tag that read

```
<c:set var="x" var="data" />
```

instead of

```
<c:set var="x" value="data" />
```

This was unusual, because the page wasn't flagging the tag's line as an error, and the stack trace (while it did mention var attribute previously defined) pointed to the taglib declaration. Fyi I am programming in Netbeans 8.0.2.

Idk, if anyone else googles this, I hope it helps!